# How to send an entity in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, temenos-quantum

How to send a `StringEntity` like java `HttpRequest` in JavaScript.i know in java but how to send in java script.

Answer (score 0):

Neither JavaScript not HTTP have any concept of a `StringEntity`.

Googling for it suggests that `StringEntity` is a Java object which is a string with some extra methods on it.

Have your JavaScript send text to the server with XMLHttpRequest (or JSONP) as you would for any other Ajax request. Turn that text into a `StringEntity` object in your server side code.